# Use ADO.NET Entity Model (.edmx) in Blazor .Net Framework

Tags: entity-framework, ado.net, blazor, blazor-server-side, dbcontext

I like to use a previous ADO.Net Entity Model, stored in another project (in the same solution) and imported like DLL in Blazor's ASP.NET Framework (not Core).

Unfortunately when i try to connect my context I receive that error: **"No connection string named 'MyDBEntities' could be found in the application config file."**.

I tried to configure appsettings.json:

```
  "ConnectionStrings": {
        "MyDBEntities": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  }
```

and the startup.cs:

```
services.AddScoped<MyDBEntities>((_) => new MyDBEntities(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDBEntities")));
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, the best solution for implement a system like ADO.NET in .Net 6 with Blazor is to use **EF Core Power Tools**, a useful design-time DbContext features for connect your DB (in my case is SQL Server) and automate the creation or update of your tables.

It's very simple to install, configure and use like ADO.NET.

For more information about how install in your Visual Studio Solution, here is the link:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ErikEJ.EFCorePowerTools

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30461861)